# How do I get rid of this type warning/error?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, scala-java-interop

I have a script. It runs without warnings.

```
$ cat ~/tmp/so1.scala 
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

class JavaMapIteratorWrapper[K,V] (map: java.util.Map[K,V]) {
  def foreach (f: Tuple2 [K, V] => Unit): Unit = {
    val iter = map.entrySet.iterator
    while (iter.hasNext) {
      val entry = iter.next
      f (entry.getKey, entry.getValue)
    }
  }
}

implicit def foreachJavaMap[K,V] (map: java.util.Map[K,V]): JavaMapIteratorWrapper[K,V] = new JavaMapIteratorWrapper[K,V](map)

val yaml = new Yaml;
(yaml load (io.Source.fromFile(argv(0)).mkString)) match {
  case map: java.util.Map [_, _] => {
    for (entry <- map) {
      entry match {
        case ("id", id: String) => System.out.println ("ID is " + id)
        case (n: String, v: String) => System.out.println (n + " = " + v)
      }
    }
  }
}

$ scala -unchecked -classpath jar/snakeyaml-1.7.jar ~/tmp/so1.scala eg/default.yaml
(program output as expected)
```

I'd like to extract the loop into its own function. So I try that.

```
$ cat ~/tmp/so2.scala 
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

class JavaMapIteratorWrapper[K,V] (map: java.util.Map[K,V]) {
  def foreach (f: Tuple2 [K, V] => Unit): Unit = {
    val iter = map.entrySet.iterator
    while (iter.hasNext) {
      val entry = iter.next
      f (entry.getKey, entry.getValue)
    }
  }
}

implicit def foreachJavaMap[K,V] (map: java.util.Map[K,V]): JavaMapIteratorWrapper[K,V] = new JavaMapIteratorWrapper[K,V](map)

val processMap = (map: java.util.Map [_, _]) => {
  for (entry <- map) {      // line 16
    entry match {
      case ("id", id: String) => System.out.println ("ID is " + id)
      case (n: String, v: String) => System.out.println (n + " = " + v)
    }
  }
}

val yaml = new Yaml;
(yaml load (io.Source.fromFile(argv(0)).mkString)) match {
  case map: java.util.Map [_, _] => processMap (map)
}

$ scala -unchecked -classpath jar/snakeyaml-1.7.jar ~/tmp/so2.scala eg/default.yaml
(fragment of so2.scala):16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : map.type (with underlying type java.util.Map[_, _])
 required: java.util.Map[_$1,_$2] where type _$2, type _$1
  for (entry <- map) {
                 ^
one error found
!!!
discarding <script preamble>
```

The loop being in its own function means it requires a more specific type. Okay.

I'll try with `java.util.Map [AnyRef, AnyRef]` instead of `java.util.Map [_, _]`.

```
$ cat ~/tmp/so3.scala 
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

class JavaMapIteratorWrapper[K,V] (map: java.util.Map[K,V]) {
  def foreach (f: Tuple2 [K, V] => Unit): Unit = {
    val iter = map.entrySet.iterator
    while (iter.hasNext) {
      val entry = iter.next
      f (entry.getKey, entry.getValue)
    }
  }
}

implicit def foreachJavaMap[K,V] (map: java.util.Map[K,V]): JavaMapIteratorWrapper[K,V] = new JavaMapIteratorWrapper[K,V](map)

val processMap = (map: java.util.Map [AnyRef, AnyRef]) => {
  for (entry <- map) {
    entry match {
      case ("id", id: String) => System.out.println ("ID is " + id)
      case (n: String, v: String) => System.out.println (n + " = " + v)
    }
  }
}

val yaml = new Yaml;
(yaml load (io.Source.fromFile(argv(0)).mkString)) match {
  case map: java.util.Map [AnyRef, AnyRef] => processMap (map)      // line 26
}

$ scala -unchecked -classpath jar/snakeyaml-1.7.jar ~/tmp/so3.scala eg/default.yaml
(fragment of so3.scala):26: warning: non variable type-argument AnyRef in type pattern is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
  case map: java.util.Map [AnyRef, AnyRef] => processMap (map)
                       ^
one warning found
!!!
discarding <script preamble>
(program output as expected)
```

So now it runs, but it gives me a warning. How do I eliminate that warning?

Notes:

1. org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml is written in Java, so I can't use type manifests. (Can I?)
2. My real program uses several Java libraries, so I want to be warned when I make possibly false assumptions about what types
   I'm being given. But how do I tell the compiler "yes, I've checked this, it's correct, don't warn me about it again"?
3. I'm using scala 2.7.7 (because that's the version that's packaged with Ubuntu).

Comment: Installing 2.8 is as simple as extracting a `.tgz` file and adding the `bin` subdirectory to your `$PATH` environment variable.  Unless you have some specific legacy code that stops you from upgrading then I'd **strongly** recommend you do so at the earliest possible opportunity. Otherwise you're missing out on over a year's worth of improvements and bug fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try removing your custom wrapper to start with.  The (2.8.1) Scala standard library already includes a wrapper to use Java collection types more idiomatically, in `scala.collection.JavaConverters`. *(note: the `scala.` prefix is not needed when importing this)*

I'd also make `processMap` a method instead of a function, and add type params:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

def processMap[K,V](map: Map[K, V]): Unit = {
  for (entry <- map) {
    entry match {
      case ("id", id: String) => System.out.println ("ID is " + id)
      case (n: String, v: String) => System.out.println (n + " = " + v)
    }
  }
}

val yaml = new Yaml
(yaml load (io.Source.fromFile(argv(0)).mkString)) match {
  case map: java.util.Map[_, _] => processMap(map.asScala)
}
```

Note the `asScala` method on the second to last line...

When dealing with Java/Scala interop, it's generally a best practice to convert from Java to Scala collections at the earliest opportunity, and to convert back as late as possible.

Comment: Accepting this answer because I upgraded to Scala 2.8.1.final. It is just as easy to treat Scala as an explicit dependency of my project as it is all the Java libraries I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using Scala 2.7.X. If you use 2.8.1, your example with Map[_,_] works fine.

If you need to use 2.7.X, try converting your processMap value into a method:
  def processMap[K,V] = (map: java.util.Map[K,V]) => {...}
That seemed to compile for me, but note that I "stubbed" the parts using the YAML library. I used:

```
val m1 = new java.util.HashMap[String,String]
m1.put("one", "1")
m1.put("id", "123")
m1.put("two", "2")

m1 match {
  case map: java.util.Map [_, _] => processMap (map)
}
```